# Keys img in React

Tags: image, reactjs, key, sensors

It's my React Component. The idea is simple.

If element is in Visibility Sensor it's adding class

**animated fade in Up** and changing **hide** -> **show**

The problem is need **key** properties for every img.

How can i create it?

```
 class Presentation extends React.Component{

          constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {IMG:'Need' +  'hide'};
            this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
          }

          onChange(isVisible)
          {
              console.log('Element is now %s', isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
              if(isVisible)
              {
                  this.setState( {IMG : 'animated fadeInUp' + ' show'} );
              }
          }

      render(){
        return(
            <div className="Presentation">

                                <VisibilitySensor onChange={this.onChange}/>

              <img className={this.state.IMG} src={one_two}/>
              <img className={this.state.IMG} src={one}/>
              <img className={this.state.IMG} src={three}/>
              <img className={this.state.IMG} src={two}/>
              <img className={this.state.IMG} src={four}/>
              <img className={this.state.IMG} src={five}/>
              <img className={this.state.IMG} src={six}/>
              <img className={this.state.IMG} src={seven}/>
              <img className={this.state.IMG} src={eight}/>
              <img className={this.state.IMG} src={nine}/>


            </div>
        )
      }
    };
```

Comment: i don't know what your approach is but if you simply want to provide different key value to every img, then i have answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the src for images in array and loop through that array and provide the index value as key to the img:

class Presentation extends React.Component{

```
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {IMG:'Need' +  'hide', 
                      srcs : [one_two,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine]
        };
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);

      }

      onChange(isVisible)
      {
          console.log('Element is now %s', isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
          if(isVisible)
          {
              this.setState( {IMG : 'animated fadeInUp' + ' show'} );
          }
      }

  render(){
    return(
        <div className="Presentation">

               <VisibilitySensor onChange={this.onChange}/>

          {
               this.state.srcs.map((src,index)=>{  
                    return (<img className={this.state.IMG} key = {index} src={src}/>);
               });

          }


        </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Comment: sorry fixed that now, use : instead of =